# How to initialize property-placeholder with environment attached to the current application context in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, properties, applicationcontext

I'm using Spring Framework 3.2.6.RELEASE.

I'm trying to set properties using command line interface (using JOptCommandLinePropertySource) via

```
PropertySource<?> propertySource = new JOptCommandLinePropertySource(options);
final GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(propertSource);
...
```

I have this beans configurer:

```
package com.example;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Value("${prop1}")
  private String prop1;

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    MyBean ret = new MyBean();
    ret.init(prop1);
    return ret;
  }
}
```

I'm starting my program with command line argument: --prop1=prop_value

If I do initialization with this xml:

```
<beans>
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:property-placeholder />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
</beans>
```

Then I get this error: *Could not resolve placeholder 'prop1' in string value "${prop1}"*

```
13:47:36.932 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'AppConfig': AutowiredFieldElement for private java.lang.String com.example.AppConfig.prop1
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AppConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.example.AppConfig.prop1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'prop1' in string value "${prop1}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
...
```

But with this xml all works fine:

```
<beans>
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="environment" ref="environment" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Why PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer does not check current application context's environment as it defined in [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html)?

> Specialization of PlaceholderConfigurerSupport that resolves ${...} placeholders within bean definition property values and @Value annotations against the current Spring Environment and its set of PropertySources.

Comment: Which spring version are  you using?

Comment: Spring Framework 3.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: Which xsd version are you using in your xml file? In other words please post the header of your configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using namespace configuration it is recommended to use the version-less xsd. So instead of `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd` one is adviced to use `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd`. This ensures that spring will use the most recent version of the xsd available on the classpath.

With regard to `<context:property-placeholder />` there where some, breaking(?), changes in Spring 3.1 in regards to the default configuration. Prior to Spring 3.1 the default-value for the `system-properties-mode` attribute was **FALLBACK**, which in Spring 3.1 leads to the creation of a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. The default is configured in the specific xsd. (As if Spring 3.1 it is **ENVIRONMENT**).

So using an older xsd leads to the default behavior belonging to that specific version of the xsd, switch to either the 3.2 xsd or the version-less xsd. (As mentioned the latter is recommended).